# Are there built-in function for average and variance value in OCaml?

Tags: r, ocaml

I find that it is convenient to use the function 
`mean()` and `var()` for calculate average and variance value in R.

I am wondering are there similar built-in function in OCaml?

```
mean(x) = sum(x)/length(x)

var(x) = sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(length(x)-1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCaml does not have these functions in the standard library.  There are however [bindings](https://bitbucket.org/mmottl/gsl-ocaml) to [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).  The [statistics bindings](http://mmottl.bitbucket.org/projects/gsl-ocaml/api/Stats.html) include mean, variance and many other functions.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the Module Stats documentation, it does provide these functions. However, I failed to install gsl-ocaml package on Windows. (OPAM installation failed too, so I have to install following the INSTALL instructions in the gsl-ocaml package.) All in all, ocaml does not work smoothly on Windows as it does on Linux/Mac. Hope ocaml team will improve in the future.